# Meteor 1.0 MiniMongo not serving objects to the client side

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working through the Discover Meteor tutorial, and even though the `Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');`  has all of its functions working on the server side Mongo shell, calling the Posts functions on the browser console is simply not working:

```
Posts.insert()
ReferenceError: Posts is not defined`
```

The collection is declared in  my `lib/collections` folder in a `posts.js` file, as such:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('posts', function(){
        return Posts.find()});
}
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('posts');
}
```

`

Any ideas or suggestions? When I run db.posts.insert({title: "postname}) in the Mongo shell, the new post shows up instantly asynchronously in the browser, so I know the DB is functioning. 
I'm pretty early on in the tutorial so I feel like this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Looks like `Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');` is defined only on the client. Is it in a `/client/...js` file perhaps, or in a `Meteor.isClient` block?

Comment: Nay, it is defined in the `/meteorapp/lib/collections` folder. It is defined and working just fine in the Mongo shell, but does not work on the client/browser-side terminal. It is in a posts.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First( just to good practices), on console run this

```
Cd myApp
meteor remove autopublish
```

Now you need to Publish (server side), Subscribe(client side), all yours Collections

```
    //server side 
    Posts = new Mongo.Collection('Posts');
   Meteor.publish('Posts', function(){
   return Posts.find()
    });

  /Client side
  Posts = new Mongo.Collection('Posts');
  Meteor.subscribe('Posts');
```

Hope This Works mate, and keep discovering Meteor

Comment: Hi, thanks!
Do I put this in the posts.js file that is in the the lib/collections/ directory?

Comment: You should use just /lib to put some librarys like jquery, momento, etc, i preffer to use /server to put Server Methods and publish and on the /client subscribe etc

Comment: do you alredy remove autopublish?

Comment: Yeah. I put a separate posts.js for the client and server in their respective folders. Restarting the server now. Will report back.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now my page is literally blank. :-( Are you sure removing autopublish was a good idea?

Comment: I don't know why, but since I've removed autopublish, nothing with meteor works. I have now created a new meteor app, and even that renders just a blank page.

Comment: bro its ok to remove autopublish, but look try meteor add:autopublish

Comment: Just wondering, should I not have my collections in the /lib/collections folder like in the discover meteor book? Just your method will be alright?

Comment: in the libraries folder you may have only libraries, bootstrap.js library, moment.js library, Jquery.js library etc, you should put collection on /client/main.js f

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web based cloud IDE?

If yes...
Do not use the javascript console that comes with your web based IDE. Run your output in a real browser like firefox or chrome and use their javascript console.

Comment: Hi Armadeus,
Thanks, but the ultimate issue was that I was running my meteor server on my Raspberry Pi, which I tunneled through a publicly accessible port. I wanted my domain name to show up in the browser's URL instead of my IP address and the port number, so I put the entire web app through a URL Frame. Unfortunately, the URL frame prevented Javascript commands from being issued from the browser's shell through the frame to the client side of the app.